# Convert string of more than 14 digit into float or any

Tags: ios

In my application I have longitude and latitude of a location on my server. When I retrieve the lat and lon from the server I save them on string.
The problem is I can not use strings in GMSCamerPosition:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latit
                                                        longitude:longt
                                                             zoom:10];
```

so I need to convert them.

I tried to convert them to integer but that could not help. Also I tried to convert them to float/ double but that also did not help because it take the number and 6 digits only after .
for example 
if this the string of latitude = 25.8837788378837

converting it to float/double produces 25.883778

Here I'm retrieving the data

```
NSURL *ur = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"......"]];    
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:ur];

json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers     error:nil];


for(int i=0; i<json.count; i++)
{
    Lng = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Lng"];
    Lat = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Lat"];
}
```

the Lng and Lat are my strings.

```
Lat = 25.431609385185958    
Lng = 49.583187103271484
```

in my case.

And Here i use them

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
double latit = [lat doubleValue];
double longt = [lon doubleValue];
NSLog(@"%f",latit);
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latit
                                                        longitude:longt
                                                             zoom:10];
```

double could not make it also. i get only this = 25.431609.

i know that i have to change NSLog to %.13f to print it all. but i did not want to print it i want to use the variable in GMSCameraPosition.

Comment: Share your conversion code. Also, sounds like you're just creating problems for yourself by converting to a string in the first place. Can't you just keep the double values?

Comment: An IEEE double precision float value contains 16 digits of precision.  You're just not printing them all.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Change your `NSLog` to use `%.13f` and be sure to use `double` and not `float` or some integer type.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is working fine as rmaddy said you're not printing all digits. Try this:

```
NSString *lat = @"25.8837788378837";
double doubleLat = [lat doubleValue];
NSLog(@"%.13f",doubleLat);
```

Comment: `doubleValue` is not a property - do not call it using property syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *lat = @"25.8837788378837";
NSLog(@"%.13f", [lat doubleValue]);
```